# Selecting every vertex above a selection (In the Z-axis)

Tags: mesh, vertices, selection-tools

i have this problem where i want to separate houses based on some data that describes the lot. My problem is that i want to be able to select the part of the model, that correspond to such a lot.

If i select some faces on the bottom of the model, i want to be able to select every vertex that is contained within the faces, and every vertex above (Like creating a bounding box around the vertices).

Is there a simple way to do this automatically. I have tried select->Active Axis, but it only works for a single vertex. If i make a script that does this for every vertex in the selection, i still only get the outer edges and not the entire lot.

[image: The lot selection]

This is the selection i can get from the lot

[image: What i want to achive (This was done manually)]

This is the result i want to achieve

I hope someone will be able to help me

- Nicolai

Comment: I guess if you had quads and not tris, your job would be much easier using loop selection tools... they don't work on tris, because the topology is not suggesting "loop paths" in any way... imho.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, if i could loop around the quads, but my idea was if i could somehow project a bounding box UP, and then select all the contained vertices. It needs not be perfect, but it would be a start

Comment: can't you just press L when the mouse is over the lot. It looks like these objects are all separate. L will select all geometry connected to the lot (ie whatever is under the mouse when you click it).

Comment: If those objects are combined, you can try to select them from the [top View for those bottom faces](http://imgur.com/fDkkJan) using Opthographic projection

Comment: The object is not separated. This is what i want to do. I want to script this so it selects autonatically, so doing it in orto view is not feasable

Comment: Doing such kind of operation using ortho view is the fastest (and afaik most used) way. You can script that and assign a shotcut on created addon, but it will be defintely much longer.